# Azure Application Insights Monitoring Metrics Issue

Tags: azure, vscode-extensions, azure-application-insights, metrics, open-telemetry-collector

I'm using Azure Application Insights to store telemetry information from my extension that I'm developing in Visual Studio Code.

In the process of doing so, I was able to send two metrics and graph them under the Metrics tab under Monitoring. However, after that when I sent my other metrics from my code, I keep on seeing the loading sign. This loading sign has been present for 2 days now.

This is what I'm seeing in Azure:
[image: Loading Image]
This is a piece of my code that I'm using to send a "thumbsUp" metric that is not showing up:

```
this.reporter = new TelemetryReporter(this.key);

this.reporter.sendTelemetryEvent('telemetryCollection', { 'stringProp': 'Numbers of times thumbs up is clicked' }, { 'thumbsUp': thumbsUp });
```

Side note: I also don't see any anything in the Failures tab under Investigate.

Comment: can you please specify which language you're using and which SDK to send telemetry?

Comment: I'm using the language Typescript, and the applicationInsights SDK to send telemetry

Comment: Would be great to capture this information, including a link to exact SDK & version.